# Why doesn't TypeORM skip() and take() function work?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typeorm, batching

The Delivery table has got more than 4 million rows. I used MySQL database.

```
async adminDeliveriesViewCount (data) {
 try {
   const batchSize = 10;
   let batchIndex = 0, totalDeliveries = 0;
   while(true) {
     let total = await Delivery.createQueryBuilder().skip(batchIndex * batchSize).take(batchSize)
       .getCount();

     if(total == 0) break;
     totalDeliveries += total;
     ++ batchIndex;
   }

   return totalDeliveries;
 } catch (e) {
   new ErrorHandler(e, 'adminDeliveriesViewCount');
 }
}
```

This function is not working. The "total" value is always the total number of rows in the table.

I tried changing the "batchSize" and "batchIndex", but it didn't help.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query instead of looping over batches?

Comment: How to do it in typeorm?

Comment: Use [`.getCount()`](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/select-query-builder#getting-a-count)

Comment: I use it on code.
let total = await Delivery.createQueryBuilder().skip(batchIndex * batchSize).take(batchSize)
       .getCount();

Comment: You shouldn't need to batch it for this.